# python3 Error collection ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

This is my tree:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── refactoring
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── refactoring.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_refactoring.py
└── requirements.txt
```

- Note: I have my virtualenv from python3.8 with pytest installed.

This is the command:

```
pytest refactoring/tests/test_refactoring.py
```

And, this is the error:

```
_____________________________ ERROR collecting refactoring/tests/test_refactoring.py _____________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/yo/projects/proyect_name/refactoring/tests/test_refactoring.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
refactoring/tests/test_refactoring.py:1: in <module>
    from refactoring import fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, result
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'refactoring'
```

The **init**.py file have 644 permissions with $USER:$USER

Now, if I remove refactoring/**init**.py it works... why? didn't it have to be both packages to import?

Comment: If you have a `refactoring.py` in a `refactoring` subpackage, then the import statement should have been `from refactoring.refactoring import fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, result`.  But don't name your modules the same as packages in the first place, that's just unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: But `from refactoring.refactoring import...` doesn't work, only if I remove refactoring/__init__.py. (I'll change the name of the subpackage, thanks)